# Are Force.com DOM id-elements worthless for Selenium Testing?

Tags: html, selenium

I just started with Saleforce/Force.com development. I set up a couple of Selenium tests last week, but they crashed today, since Salesforce upgraded to Version Winter '14 on my Dev Sandbox. My Selenium tests rely on the id-tags within the DOM, which now have other numbers.

I would like to know on which DOM elements you guys rely on to run Selenium tests?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Selenium IDE or Selenium Webdriver?

I'm using the latter and match Salesforce Ids using css selectors - if your visualforce is annotated with Ids then your id will always appear at the end of the salesforce generated Id.  For example:

A visualforce entry like this:

```
<apex:inputField id="accountName" value="{!CustomObjectX__c.Account__c}" required="true">
```

Will be rendered as this mess:

```
<input id="j_id0:j_id1:TheForm:j_id77:j_id78:j_id79:accountName" maxlength="255" name="j_id0:j_id1:TheForm:j_id77:j_id78:j_id79:accountName" onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1:TheForm',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:TheForm:j_id77:j_id78:j_id79:accountName:j_id82','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:TheForm:j_id77:j_id78:j_id79:accountName:j_id82':'j_id0:j_id1:TheForm:j_id77:j_id78:j_id79:accountName:j_id82'} ,'containerId':'j_id0:j_id1:TheForm:j_id77:j_id78:j_id79:j_id81'} )" size="20" type="text" value="The Account Name">
```

meaning you can reference the component using the following css selector:

```
"input[id$='accountName']"
```

(An input that has an id which ends with accountName - signified by the $=)

This will then match in any org your code is deployed to.  Using selectors gives you more flexibility too, you can match on other attributes of the rendered html.  Take a look at [CSS selectors for Selenium](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples) which gives a good starting overview and also covers how to use such selectors if you are using Selenium IDE

Answer (score 2):

I would stay away from using ID tags for automated testing, if you are testing a VF page you can use the class name instead.

Comment: What would you recommend then for a test using/requiring standard pages? Button or link values (such as "Edit" or "Save") or something else?

Comment: I was thinking about using class names as unique identifiers, but I do not have access to it - yet. For now I use XPath Queries and I hope that the DOM wont change.